# Cannot convert a symbolic Keras input/output to a numpy array error when subclassing tf.keras.Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to build an UNet type architecture with EfficientNet backbone from tensorflow.keras.applications, and I'm running into this error when fitting the model, even though I don't use any numpy computations within the model definition. The error below occurs when I try to call model.fit() with the actual data, which is in the form of a tf.data.Dataset of image and mask pairs (the purpose of the model is to do instance segmentation of images).

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_36/1715282830.py in <module>
      1 history = model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=1,
----> 2                     validation_data=val_dataset, verbose=1)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1182                 _r=1):
   1183               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1184               tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
   1185               if data_handler.should_sync:
   1186                 context.async_wait()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    883 
    884       with OptionalXlaContext(self._jit_compile):
--> 885         result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    886 
    887       new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    931       # This is the first call of __call__, so we have to initialize.
    932       initializers = []
--> 933       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
    934     finally:
    935       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
    758     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
    759         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 760             *args, **kwds))
    761 
    762     def invalid_creator_scope(*unused_args, **unused_kwds):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   3064       args, kwargs = None, None
   3065     with self._lock:
-> 3066       graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   3067     return graph_function
   3068 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   3461 
   3462           self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
-> 3463           graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   3464           self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   3465 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   3306             arg_names=arg_names,
   3307             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
-> 3308             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
   3309         self._function_attributes,
   3310         function_spec=self.function_spec,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes, acd_record_initial_resource_uses)
   1005         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
   1006 
-> 1007       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
   1008 
   1009       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    666         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
    667         with OptionalXlaContext(compile_with_xla):
--> 668           out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    669         return out
    670 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    992           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    993             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 994               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    995             else:
    996               raise

TypeError: in user code:

    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py:853 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py:842 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1286 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2849 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:3632 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py:835 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py:789 train_step
        y, y_pred, sample_weight, regularization_losses=self.losses)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py:240 __call__
        total_loss_metric_value, sample_weight=batch_dim)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/utils/metrics_utils.py:73 decorated
        update_op = update_state_fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/metrics.py:177 update_state_fn
        return ag_update_state(*args, **kwargs)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/metrics.py:410 update_state  **
        sample_weight, values)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/weights_broadcast_ops.py:157 broadcast_weights
        values = ops.convert_to_tensor(values, name="values")
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/profiler/trace.py:163 wrapped
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:1566 convert_to_tensor
        ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py:346 _constant_tensor_conversion_function
        return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py:272 constant
        allow_broadcast=True)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py:290 _constant_impl
        allow_broadcast=allow_broadcast))
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py:435 make_tensor_proto
        values = np.asarray(values)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py:83 asarray
        return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/keras_tensor.py:245 __array__
        'Cannot convert a symbolic Keras input/output to a numpy array. '

    TypeError: Cannot convert a symbolic Keras input/output to a numpy array. This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a symbolic value to a NumPy call, which is not supported. Or, you may be trying to pass Keras symbolic inputs/outputs to a TF API that does not register dispatching, preventing Keras from automatically converting the API call to a lambda layer in the Functional Model.
```

I suspect that the error comes from the way I subclassed Model(), but the thing is, I can still call model.build(). From looking at the error log, there is a call to make_tensor_proto which takes np.asarray(values) where values here is likely the Tensor itself, which is causing the error.

```
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py:346 _constant_tensor_conversion_function
        return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py:272 constant
        allow_broadcast=True)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py:290 _constant_impl
        allow_broadcast=allow_broadcast))
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py:435 make_tensor_proto
        values = np.asarray(values)
```

The code for the model:

```
def decoder_block(x, skip_layer, filters, kernel_size, dropout_rate=0.1, **kwargs):
    x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters=filters, kernel_size=kernel_size,
                               strides=(2, 2), padding="same", **s_config)(x)
    x = layers.Concatenate()([x, skip_layer])
    x = layers.Conv2D(filters=filters, kernel_size=kernel_size, strides=(1, 1),
                      padding="same", **s_config)(x)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = layers.AlphaDropout(rate=dropout_rate, seed=global_seed)(x)

    x = layers.Conv2D(filters=filters, kernel_size=kernel_size, strides=(1, 1),
                      padding="same", **s_config)(x)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
    return x


class UNet(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self,
                 model_size="base",
                 num_classes=3,
                 img_size=224,
                 filters_root=32,
                 kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 backbone=None,
                 dropout_rate=.0,
                 dropout_decay=None,
                 local_pooling_layer=layers.MaxPool2D((2, 2)),
                 **kwargs
                 ):
        super().__init__(self, name="UNet", **kwargs)
        if model_size not in ["small", "base"]:
            model_size = "base"
            print("Model size input is not amongst {}. Model size is defaulted to base.".format(["small", "base"]))
        self.model_size = model_size
        self.num_classes = num_classes
        self.img_size = img_size
        self.filters_root = filters_root
        self.kernel_size = kernel_size
        self.backbone = backbone if backbone else get_unet_backbone(
            backbone_name="Efficient_net", pretrained_weights="imagenet")
        self.backbone.trainable = False  # we aren't training the encoder backbone
        self.dropout_rate = dropout_rate  # dropout is applied in each conv_block

    def call(self, input_layer):
        # set backbone encoder to take input
        x = self.backbone(input_layer)

        # encoder layers in order of top down (with input intake at the top)
        encoder_output_layer_names = [l.name for l in self.backbone.layers if "a_activation" in l.name]
        encoder = [self.backbone.get_layer(name) for name in encoder_output_layer_names]
        if self.model_size == "small":
            encoder = encoder[:3] + encoder[-2:]

        # bridge connection
        bridge = encoder.pop(-1).output

        # decoder layers
        for idx in range(len(encoder) - 1, 0, -1):
            x = decoder_block(bridge,
                              encoder[idx].output,
                              filters=self.filters_root * 2 ** idx,
                              kernel_size=self.kernel_size,
                              dropout_rate=self.dropout_rate)

        # output layer
        outputs = layers.Conv2D(1, kernel_size=(1, 1), padding="same",
                                activation="sigmoid",
                                kernel_initializer=LecunNormal(seed=global_seed),
                                bias_initializer=LecunNormal(seed=global_seed))(x)

        return outputs
```

Loss and optimizers are detailed here.

```
model.compile(
    loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False) ,
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-4), 
    metrics=['accuracy']
)
```

My numpy and TensorFlow versions are 1.19.5 and 2.6.0 respectively.

Comment: please post your full error log and also the code that causing it

Comment: I included the error logs and a bit more explanation for the problem. I hope that explains it in more details.

Comment: what loss function did you use?

Comment: I copied the model.compile() call from another piece of code and apparently it was an "accuracy" metric, which might be incompatible with the final layer, and I'm thinking this is where the problem occurs. I'll fix the model metrics and update the post if it works out. Thank you

Comment: Hi ! Could you try again by disabling eager execution using tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution() command at beginning of your code or upgrading Numpy version manually to 1.21.4 ? Thanks!